# Precompiling a .scss manifest file using Rails 3.1's asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, sprockets, asset-pipeline

The release version of Rails 3.1 is having some weird issues with precompiling a sass manifest file with the extension `scss`. The weird thing is that the default manifest file `application.scss` compiles fine and I see it under `public/assets/`.

However when I try to compile my custom manifest files, nothing is created. I have enabled the precompile option in the production config.

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( user.scss admin.scss )
```

I am running the precompile rake task correctly as far a I know.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

And maybe this helps. When I create two new manifest files with the extension **css** instead of **scss** and require the original scss files in them, then these new manifest files are honored and properly compiled. Why does `application.scss` get this special treatment and not other sass manifest files?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Include the *compiled* filenames in your precompile list:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( user.css admin.css )
```

Also, you may want to to rename the original files in `app/assets/stylesheets` to include the compiled extension in the original filenames so it's clear what is going on:

```
user.scss -> user.css.scss
admin.scss -> admin.css.scss
```

Answer (score -2):

I suspect it might be  bug.

The `application` files are treated as the main files for a default project. The one ending in .css and .js are included in the precompile list by default.

The behavior you describe (manifests having a .css extension) is the correct one.