# Rails Assets custom manifests are not precompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a scenario as follows. I've built a "themed" site using the asset pipeline. There are a variety of manifests:

```
application.scss
application_light.scss
application_dark.scss
```

When I run `rake assets:precompile`, only application.scss gets compiled and created as application.css.

I have no trouble with these assets in development, it is only in production pre-compilation that they fail.

I have tried:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application_light.scss )
```

This also does not work, it simply does not precompile anything past `application.scss`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

[Precompiling a .scss manifest file using Rails 3.1's asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367864/precompiling-a-scss-manifest-file-using-rails-3-1s-asset-pipeline)

Turns out I just needed to change the precompile to css from scss.

Comment: Did you mean from `scss` to `css`?