# Rails Precompiling Custom Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a custom `application_admin.css.scss` under `app/assets/stylesheets`

and I have this line in my `config/environments/production.rb` file

```
config.assets.precompile += [%w(application_admin.css)]
```

When I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` the custom stylesheet doesn't compile

I came across this post but I already have what they suggested. 
[Rails Assets custom manifests are not precompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078963/rails-assets-custom-manifests-are-not-precompiling)

What else should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to use both `[]` and the `%w()`.  Try just:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application_admin.css )
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['application_admin.css']
```

Second, since you are precompiling for your *production* environment you want to run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Just:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

runs it for your development environment by default.  You will want to run this in each environment you want to precomplie your assests in.

Comment: no didn't do anything. "$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
                        $ "

Comment: @Newbie, Since you put it in your production.rb file you may want to do a:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: yes that worked! change the solution to including the environment and I will accept it. also do we run bundle exec rake assets:precompile for each environment separately?

Comment: Thank you! using [] wasn't a problem by the way, just an extra thing that I didn't need. It is specifically the environment that solved my problem.