# rails - application.css asset not found in production mode

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading an application to use the asset pipeline.

I've got the css assets compiling into an application css file but they not being found when I run the application in production mode with

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s
```

and I visit any page I get the correct output from the database but no styling and the log shows:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] 
"/assets/default.scss-1a27c...f07c.css"):
```

Even though that file exists in public/assets

```
$ ls public/assets/def*
public/assets/default.scss-1a27c...f07c.css     public/assets/default.scss.css
public/assets/default.scss-1a27c...f07c.css.gz  public/assets/default.scss.css.gz
```

What do I need to change to get the server to find the asset file?

Same is happening for my other .css files.  They get compiled into public/assets with finger prints but then are not found.

Page source is showing:

```
<link href="/assets/default.scss-1a27c...f07c.css" 
media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The rails (haml) source is `= stylesheet_link_tag 'default.scss.css'`

`public.assets` curently includes has the following files.

```
$ ls public/assets/def*
public/assets/default.scss-1a27c22229b7b522066181f27af4f07c.css
public/assets/default.scss-1a27c22229b7b522066181f27af4f07c.css.gz
public/assets/default.scss.css
public/assets/default.scss.css.gz
```

application.rb has

```
$ cat config/application.rb 
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Linker
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false # For Heroku
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

`config/environments/production` has:

```
$ cat config/environments/production.rb 
Linker::Application.configure do
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.assets.precompile += ['default.scss.css','main.css', 'jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css']
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

This seems to be happening for all assets, e.g.

```
Started GET "/assets/default.scss-1a27c22229b7b522066181f27af4f07c.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-23 10:24:47 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/default.scss-1a27c22229b7b522066181f27af4f07c.css"):
Started GET "/assets/main-6864687b4114a1c316e444bd90f233ff.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-23 10:24:47 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/main-6864687b4114a1c316e444bd90f233ff.css"):
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom-24319b4b1218846a3fe22a0479ae98b4.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-23 10:24:47 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom-24319b4b1218846a3fe22a0479ae98b4.css"):
Started GET "/assets/application-fc1d492d730f2a45581a40eac4607db8.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-23 10:24:47 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-fc1d492d730f2a45581a40eac4607db8.js"):
Started GET "/images/link.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-23 10:24:48 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/link.ico"):
```

Comment: did you do `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Yes I did `$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and restarted my server

Comment: can you copy your application.rb and production.rb files?

Comment: chek this question and the answer, you seem to have wrong names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367864/precompiling-a-scss-manifest-file-using-rails-3-1s-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Rails by default doesn't serve assets under `public`. See your `production.rb`:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Change that to true and you're good to go. (Note: you don't want that to be `true` in production, remember to change it back before deploying!)

See [Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) for details.

**In rails 6**, in the default `production.rb` there should be a line

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

So run your server with

```
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true rails server -e production
```

or set `config.public_file_server.enabled=true` in `production.rb`.  See answers below for rails 4 and 5.

Comment: Why should it be false in production? I am using rails_12factor and heroku. Thank you for any further explanation!

Comment: @LeoBrown Rails assumes that in production, you have a web server (Apache, nginx) running before Rails, or even a CDN specifically for static assets. Any of those can serve static assets much faster than Rails.

Comment: For Rails 5 : set `config.public_file_server.enabled` to `true` in `config/environments/production.rb`.

Comment: @vmarquet, I just spent way too much time searching for this answer... Devise `<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete) %>` in production mode brought me here for those who will inevitably follow. Thanks!

Comment: I would just add, that in Rails 5 the config flag is set by `ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` That means you can run your server with `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1 rails server --environment production` and you will be good to go without changing the config file.

Comment: @awendt I'm pretty new to back-end web work (experienced otherwise) and would appreciate any elaboration on your comment here. It sounds like it could be the focus of an entire book. You're saying I would want to have apache and rails running side by side on the same machine to separately serve different parts of the site, the static assets vs the rails-produced html ?

Answer (score 12):

The Rails 5 solution is similar to the [Rails 4 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32538854) given by Jules Copeland above.

In your pre-generated `config/environments/production.rb` file, there should be an entry that looks something like this:

```
# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
# Apache or NGINX already handles this.
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

I found a decent explanation for this setting in the [Configuring Rails Applications guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) at http://guides.rubyonrails.org:

> config.public_file_server.enabled configures Rails to serve static
>   files from the public directory. This option defaults to true, but in
>   the production environment it is set to false because the server
>   software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the application should
>   serve static files instead. If you are running or testing your app in
>   production mode using WEBrick (it is not recommended to use WEBrick in
>   production) set the option to true. Otherwise, you won't be able to
>   use page caching and request for files that exist under the public
>   directory.

**Conclusion**: In production, starting your rails server with `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1` will allow Rails to serve any files in the public/assets directory just as a web server would. Keep in mind, Rails is an app server and will not do this as efficiently as a web server (e.g. NGINX, Apache, etc.). For real-world applications, you should have a dedicated web server sitting in front of Rails which will serve static assets by itself and only bother Rails for dynamic content as needed. For more details, see [this article](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/a-web-server-vs-an-app-server/) by Justin Weiss on the differences between web servers and app servers.

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 4, you can get them to show in production (running locally), by passing an environment variable:

`RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true rails server -e production`

This should work as long as you have this line in `/config/environments/production.rb`:

config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

Answer (score 4):

When you do `rake assets:precompile`, your assets go into public directory. See if you can find those files in `public/assets/`

You should see something like this:

```
I, [2014-02-23T20:06:21.853314 #26915]  INFO -- : Writing app_root/public/assets/application-ecd8636fc80ea2b712039c4abc365da9.css
```

Comment: when you precompile, which directory does it write to?

Comment: +1 Thanks, It seems to be writing to public/assets at least that's where the finger printed files are.

Comment: does the newly written file name and the filename that is being requested match?

Comment: I added more output from public/assets in the question.

Comment: Are you saying file exists and your web server is not rendering it? Problem with your web server. Not Rails. Try visiting that URL manually - `app/assets/application....css`

Comment: `(No route matches [GET] "/assets/default.scss-1a27c22229b7b522066181f27af4f0
7c.css"):` in the log seems to match `$ ls public/assets/default*.css
public/assets/default.scss-1a27c22229b7b522066181f27af4f07c.css `

Comment: ok, hmm, that gives me `(No route matches [GET] "/assets/default.scss-1a27c22229b7b522066181f27af4f07c.css"):`

Comment: Been bitten by this more than once. Please see my answer.