# Rails error after creates new page ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a `maintanance_mode` page in my rails app. So I've created `StaticPagesController` with `maintanance_mode` method (it's empty) and views `views/static_page/maintanance_mode.html.erb` with routes below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'react#index',
  get: '/maintanance_mode', to: 'static_pages#maintanance_mode'

  scope 'api' do
    use_doorkeeper do
      skip_controllers :applications, :authorized_applications, :authorizations
    end
  end
```

I was trying to get into this page (simple `Hello`) but I've got an error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
     8:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     9:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    10:
    11:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    12:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    13:   </head>
    14:
```

Comment: is there an `application.css` file in the assets\sytlesheets folder?

Comment: Error at the top shows code from `application.html.erb`, there is only application.scss in `javascript/src/scenes/base/style/application.scss`

Comment: this isn't a static page, since it is an erb, so it is using the application layout.  if you want a true static page, make it an html page and stick it in /public.  Will also need to configure rails to serve static pages.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969549/rails-application-css-asset-not-found-in-production-mode

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple, I have to add `application.css` with below code

`application.css`

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```